# Should I undo a downvote when the answer is gradually edited to a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Now and then I decide to downvote an answer because I feel it's wrong beyond redemption, and comment on the reason for the downvote. Instead of removing the answer, the answerer prefers to edit it, often leaving the original point behind completely, and in the worst case only duplicating content from overall better answers.

---

The answer that stimulated the question was this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25168153/371191

The original answer read:

> Concurrency (the `Thread` class and such) is an added feature in v1.5 of [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29). `i++` was added long before that, and as such it still more than likely in its (more or less) original implementation.

Which is wrong in fact and intent. He goes on and changes this to:

> Concurrency (the `Thread` class and such) is an added feature in v1.0 of [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29). `i++` was added in the beta before that, and as such is it still more than likely in its (more or less) original implementation.

And finally adds this:

> Edit: To clarify, i++ is a well defined procedure that predates Java, and as such the designers of Java decided to keep the original functionality of that procedure.
>
> The ++ operator was defined in B (1969) which predates java and threading by just a tad.

While the wrong content remains, this edit has some merit, but it duplicates a point better made by another answer:

> You could make the argument that i++ should have been designed and documented as specifically performing an atomic increment, so that a non-atomic increment is performed using i = i + 1. However, this would break the "cultural compatibility" between Java, and C and C++. As well, it would take away a convenient notation which programmers familiar with C-like languages take for granted, giving it a special meaning that applies only in limited circumstances.

---

In this particular case, as the original part is still wrong as far as I'm concerned, it's clear for me to leave the downvote. But often, an answer with a history like this one has its original content completely removed, so it's not "clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect" any more. However, I don't feel like such an answer deserves the downvote to be removed.

I know that votes are my own anyway, as long as I don't abuse them, but I'd like to know what the general consensus is on such an issue, if any, and what you'd have done.

Comment: The question is unproductive at best. As HotLicks mentioned in a comment [Why would you even expect it to be atomic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168062/why-is-i-not-atomic-in-java/25168153#comment39190685_25168062).